# How to get request extension in express?

Tags: node.js, express

How to understand if somebody requests image or file in express? For example:

```
https://example.com/image.png
https://example.com/file.js
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
app.get("/:fileName", (req, res) => {
    const file = req.params.fileName.split(".");
    const fileExtension = file[file.length-1];

    const imageExtensions = ["png", "jpg"];

    if(imageExtensions.includes(fileExtension) {
        console.log("It's an image");
    } else if (fileExtension === "js") {
        console.log("It's a javascript file");
    }

    return res.send();
});
```

But i would recommend to just separate the routes per resource type, for example:

```js
app.get("/img/:fileName", (req, res) => {
    console.log(`Getting image ${req.params.fileName}`);
    return res.send();
});


app.get("/js/:fileName", (req, res) => {
    console.log(`Getting JS file ${req.params.fileName}`);
    return res.send();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Once the server received the request, you can check for the extension of the url and later process it. [need more information to know exactly what you need]